# How to find a scalar field, given its gradient?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

Given that a vector field $\mathbf v$ satisfies
$$\nabla \cdot\mathbf v =0.$$

How can I find $\phi(\mathbf r)$ such that $\mathbf v= \nabla \phi$?

Comment: I think either you mean $\mathbf{v}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, or you need $\nabla\times\mathbf{v}=0$ in the first place.

Comment: @user10354138 No, i just mean what i say above

Comment: A divergence-free vector field need not be conservative.

Comment: For example, $\mathbf{v}=y\mathbf{e}_x$ is divergence-free, but there are no $\phi$ that makes $\mathbf{v}=\nabla\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $\mathbf v= \nabla \phi$ gives $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$

This is a famous equation called Laplace's Equation. Any PDE book will teach you methods to solve it.

Comment: But then you are ignoring the imformation of $\mathbf v$.

Comment: No I'm not. All we know is that $\nabla \cdot\mathbf v =0$. This information is preserved on substituting $\mathbf v= \nabla \phi$ to get $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$

Comment: No. The information is not limited to $\nabla\cdot \mathbf v=0$. We know all values of $\mathbf v=0$ at any point. We know everything about it.